# Prototyped Method returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript, object, prototype, paperjs

Having a bit of trouble running an objects method and am pretty new to OOP. I have the following constructor class:

```
function Blob(c, maxRadius, points, v) {

    this.vector = v;
    this.maxVector = 5;
    this.center = c;


    this.path = new Path();
    this.path.closed = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < points; i++) {
        var delta = new Point({
            length: (maxRadius * 0.5) + (Math.random() * maxRadius * 0.5),
            angle: (360 / points) * i
        });
        this.path.add(center + delta);
    }
    this.path.smooth();
    this.path.fillColor = colors[i % 3];
};
```

Which I then want to prototype the following methods to each "blob" object

```
Blob.prototype = {
    iterate: function() {
        this.checkBorders();
        if (this.vector.length > this.maxVector)
            this.vector.length = this.maxVector
        this.center += this.vector;

    },
    checkBorders: function() {
        var size = view.size;
        if (this.center.x < -this.radius)
            this.center.x = size.width + this.radius;
        if (this.center.x > size.width + this.radius)
            this.center.x = -this.radius;
        if (this.center.y < -this.radius)
            this.center.y = size.height + this.radius;
        if (this.center.y > size.height + this.radius)
            this.center.y = -this.radius;
    }
};
```

I then call the constructor class within a new function that in turn passes the arguments needed to the constructor class:

```
function createPaths() {
    var radiusDelta = values.maxRadius - values.minRadius;
    var pointsDelta = values.maxPoints - values.minPoints;

    for (var i = 0; i < values.paths; i++) {
        var radius = values.minRadius + Math.random() * radiusDelta;
        var points = values.minPoints + Math.floor(Math.random() * pointsDelta);
        var center = view.size * Point.random();
        var vector = new Point({
            angle: 360 * Math.random(),
            length: Math.random() * 10
        });

        blobs.push(Blob(center, radius, points, vector));
    };
}
```

But when I try and access it from within a function:

```
function onFrame() {
    for (var i = 0; i < blobs.length - 1; i++) {
        blobs[i].iterate();
    }
}
```

it returns

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'iterate' of undefined", it seems to me then that the prototype is failing? When I console "blobs[i]" from within onFrame() it returns the array of objects I would expect to find so it doesn't seem like it's any issue with the class constructor function... Any help much appreciated!

Comment: It's not the prototype. Your `blobs` array has an `undefined` value in it somewhere.

Comment: I would add to the prototype instead of redefining it: `Blob.prototype.iterate = function() { ... }`

Comment: how do you fill the `blobs` array ?

Comment: Sorry, please see above for how I populate the array, I added it in my edit

Comment: You're leaving `new` out when you construct Blob instances. The constructor when called without `new` will return `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the array filling to use new so that you create distinct objects

```
blobs.push(new Blob(center, radius, points, vector));
```

You current code just executes the `Blob` function which returns nothing (*`undefined`*)

Comment: Do you ever feel like punching yourself in the face?! Haha thanks for that, obviously just needed a fresh pair of eyes

Answer (score 0):

Add to the prototype instead of redefining it:

```
Blob.prototype.checkBorders = function() { ... };
Blob.prototype.iterate = function() { ... };
```

and don't forget the `new` keyword new instantiating new blob objects.